# Is there a way to get CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to only store date, hours and minutes in a database?

Tags: database, postgresql, table-plus

I'm storing data in PostgreSQL with one column set to a default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. I'm trying to get this default to only store: date, hours and minutes. Does anyone know how I can do it?

I need to be able to manipulate the data using Ruby to then display it on an html page. At the moment I can display a timestamp like this: `2019-09-15 12:50:05.745811` but would like something more like this: `2019-09-15 12:50`.

At the moment I'm extracting each row of a table into a Ruby object and defining each value as accessible instance variable so `@id = id`, `@content = content` and `@timestamp = timestamp`. I would like a way to either edit a string like this: `2019-09-15 12:50:05.745811` in ruby or what I guess might be easier to find a way for the `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to only store the relevant data. Any help, much appreciated.

This is how my table has been created:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  content VARCHAR(280), 
  timestamp timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **always** want your date resolution only to the second then you can specify that in the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  content VARCHAR(280), 
  timestamp timestamp(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

If you want the capability to process and/or display fractional seconds then make the  conversion when selecting:

```
Select ..., timestamp::timestamp(0) ...
```

When you want to show less the second precision then you must use to_char(...) and specify the mask for what you want, So in your example 2019-09-15 12:50:

```
select ... to_char(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:'), ...
```

IMHO it is very bad practice to name a column the same as a data type. It **will** at sometime cause confusion or mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for the explainer I much appreciate it as a novice to both Ruby and data manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_char()` to remove everything after the minutes and `to_timestamp()` to convert back to `timestamp`:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  content VARCHAR(280), 
  timestamp timestamp DEFAULT to_timestamp(to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=3a9a5783d2ba8b807c38f744e7c8e9a6).

Comment: Thanks, that gets me slightly closer to how I wanted to get it displayed, still seems to have some trailing 00 seconds at the end. This is how it looks like: 2019-09-15 15:06:00

Comment: The data type of the column is timestamp. If you did not want a timestamp you should declare it as varchar(). Then you only need to_char(...)